# How do I schedule jobs in Jenkins on specific time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow, build-triggers

For every +61 minute e.g. 00:00, 01:01, 02:02, 03:03 ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Jenkins uses cron expression, there isn't a way to run a script every 61 minutes. You can have another options checking this already answered question: 
[How to set crontab every 1 hour 1 minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082202/how-to-set-crontab-every-1-hour-1-minute)